# How to Select new model list after GroupBy mothod in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, model, group-by

I want select grouped rows to a new model list.this is my code:

```
List<Model_Bulk> q = (from a in db.Advertises 
                      join c in db.Companies on a.AdvertiseCompanyID equals c.CompanyID
                      where a.AdvertiseActive == true 
                            && a.AdvertiseExpireDate.HasValue 
                            && a.AdvertiseExpireDate.Value > DateTime.Now 
                            && (a.AdvertiseObjectType == 1 
                                || a.AdvertiseObjectType == 2)
                      select c)
     .GroupBy(a => a.CompanyID).Select(a => new Model_Bulk
     {
         CompanyEmail = a.CompanyContactInfo.Email,
         CompanyID = a.CompanyID,
         CompanyName = a.CompanyName,
         Mobile = a.CompanyContactInfo.Cell,
         UserEmail = a.User1.Email,
         categories = a.ComapnyCategories
     }).ToList();
```

After group by, i can not use Select and naturally this syntax error raised:

> System.Linq.IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'CompanyContactInfo' and no extension method 'CompanyContactInfo' accepting a first argument of type
>   System.Linq.IGrouping' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If i try with SelectMany() method.but the result will repeated and groupby method not work properly:

```
List<Model_Bulk> q = (from a in db.Advertises
                      join c in db.Companies on a.AdvertiseCompanyID equals c.CompanyID
                      where a.AdvertiseActive == true 
                            && a.AdvertiseExpireDate.HasValue 
                            && a.AdvertiseExpireDate.Value > DateTime.Now 
                            && (a.AdvertiseObjectType == 1 
                                || a.AdvertiseObjectType == 2)
                      select c)
     .GroupBy(a => a.CompanyID).SelectMany(a => a).Select(a => new Model_Bulk
     {
         CompanyEmail = a.CompanyContactInfo.Email,
         CompanyID = a.CompanyID,
         CompanyName = a.CompanyName,
         Mobile = a.CompanyContactInfo.Cell,
         UserEmail = a.User1.Email,
         categories = a.ComapnyCategories
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: try a.First().CompanyContactInfo.Email ... for its a group ...

Comment: same for the other properties...

Comment: using .Select(a => a.FirstOrDefault()).Select... after group by in solution.thanks for your hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `.SelectMany(a => a)` you can use `.Select(g => g.First())`.That will give you the first item of each group.

```
(from a in db.Advertises
                          join c in db.Companies on a.AdvertiseCompanyID equals c.CompanyID
                          where a.AdvertiseActive == true && a.AdvertiseExpireDate.HasValue && a.AdvertiseExpireDate.Value > DateTime.Now && (a.AdvertiseObjectType == 1 || a.AdvertiseObjectType == 2)
                          select c)
             .GroupBy(a => a.CompanyID)
             .Select(g => g.First())
             .Select(a => new Model_Bulk
             {
                 CompanyEmail = a.CompanyContactInfo.Email,
                 CompanyID = a.CompanyID,
                 CompanyName = a.CompanyName,
                 Mobile = a.CompanyContactInfo.Cell,
                 UserEmail = a.User1.Email,
                 categories = a.ComapnyCategories
             }).ToList();
```

Note that this might not be supported, if that is the case add an `AsEnumerable` call before `.Select(g => g.First())`

Comment: great and work properly.but i must use FirstorDefault instead of First().Please Edit your useful post.thanks Selman

Answer (score 1):

You should understand that after you do `GroupBy()` in your **LinQ** expresstion you work with a **group** so in your example it will be good to write like this:

```
List<Model_Bulk> q = 
    (from a in db.Advertises join c in db.Companies on a.AdvertiseCompanyID equals c.CompanyID                          
    where a.AdvertiseActive == true 
    && a.AdvertiseExpireDate.HasValue 
    && a.AdvertiseExpireDate.Value > DateTime.Now 
    && (a.AdvertiseObjectType == 1 || a.AdvertiseObjectType == 2)
    select c)
                 .GroupBy(a => a.CompanyID)
                 .Select(a => new Model_Bulk
                 {
                     CompanyEmail = a.First().CompanyContactInfo.Email,
                     CompanyID = a.Key, //Note this line, it's can be happened becouse of GroupBy()
                     CompanyName = a.First().CompanyName,
                     Mobile = a.First().CompanyContactInfo.Cell,
                     UserEmail = a.First().User1.Email,
                     categories = a.First().ComapnyCategories
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: good and works fine with a change.but i must use FirstOrDefault() method in all columns.using Select(g => g.First()) after groupby is better.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you could try something like this, instead of mixing query expressions and methods... (using FirstOrDefault() in the where / select as necessary)

```
(from a in db.Advertises
join c in db.Companies on a.AdvertiseCompanyID equals c.CompanyID
group a by new { a.CompanyId } into resultsSet
where resultsSet.AdvertiseActive == true && resultsSet.AdvertiseExpireDate.HasValue && resultsSet.AdvertiseExpireDate.Value > DateTime.Now && (resultsSet.AdvertiseObjectType == 1 || resultsSet.AdvertiseObjectType == 2)
select new Model_Bulk
{
    CompanyEmail = resultsSet.CompanyContactInfo.Email,
    CompanyID = resultsSet.CompanyID,
    CompanyName = resultsSet.CompanyName,
    Mobile = resultsSet.CompanyContactInfo.Cell,
    UserEmail = resultsSet.User1.Email,
    categories = resultsSet.ComapnyCategories
}).ToList();
```

Comment: this code works if i add FirstOrDefault() method for each field of resulstSet in 'Where' and 'select new'.so the query works fine but with lower speed